# wait_for() multiple user discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need my bot to wait for multiple user inputs. for example
if I called a command (`'!invite @user1 @user2 @user3'`) in discord server!

It should wait until all the mentioned user says `"@mentionme accept"`
Now the problem is, I Can Do it for one mention (`'!invite @user1'`) but I can't do for multiple users.
here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def invite(ctx,*,message):
    mentioned_users = [member for member in message.mentions]#get all mentioned users
    def check(message: discord.Message):
        return message.channel == ctx.channel and message.author.id in mentioned_users and message.content == f"{ctx.author.mention} accept"
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check,timeout=40.0)#wait_for
    await ctx.channel.send(f'{member.mention} accepted the invitation!')
```

It works for only one mention! Is there anyother ways to use the `wait_for` function for multiple users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a list with all the mentions and remove from it

```py
@bot.command()
async def invite(ctx, *mentions: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send('Waiting for everyone to accept the invitation...')
    # Converting the tuple to list so we can remove from it
    mentions = list(mentions)
    def check(message):
        if message.channel == ctx.channel and message.author in mentions and message.content.lower() == f'{ctx.author.mention} accept':
            # Removing the member from the mentions list
            mentions.remove(message.author)
            # If the length of the mentions list is 0 means that everyone accepted the invite
            if len(mentions) == 0:
                return True
        return False
    
    await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    await ctx.send('Everyone accepted the invitation!')
```